# PHP- if statement not evaluating to true despite the values being compared are logically verified to be true

Tags: php, mysql

The value of valid is coming from another page after redirection.In the address bar the value of valid=%273%27.
The value is echoing as '3', but still the if statement is evaluating to false.In the database table i have declared the type for variable valid as INT. I have tried changing the type for variable valid into TINYINT and ENUM and VARCHAR also,but to no use.

```
<?php
     $output="";
     if($_GET['valid']==3)
     {
                $output.="<br/><br/><br/>
                <h2>You are just one step behind completing your Profile.Please Upload Your Photo Here:</h2>
                <br/><br/><br/>";
               $output.="<form action=\"loadStudent.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
                $output.="<table>";
                $output.="<tr>";
        $output.="<td align=\"right\"><font size=\"2\" face=\"Arial\"><strong>Picture</strong></font></td>";
         $output.="<td align=\"center\">:</td>";
         $output.="<td>";
         $output.="<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" value=\"10485760\">";
         $output.="<input type=\"file\" name=\"image\"  id=\"file\" size=\"255\"> <font size=\"5\" face=\"Arial\"> Maxsize 1MB</font>";
         $output.="</td>";
       $output.="</tr>";
      $output.="<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</td><td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></td>";
                    $output.=" </tr>";
                     $output.="</table>";
                 $output.="</form>";
                 echo $userId;
    echo $output;   

    }//if($valid==3)
    echo $_GET['valid'];
    ?>
```

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek what is 'inline HTML'?

Comment: @Ryan I guess he's saying templating is the way to go now

Comment: @MattThompson so, youare going to post a long adult lecture on the topic, aren't you?

Comment: @MattThompson I am sorry to disappoint you, but by no means this site is a forum and rather not for "help", but for answering questions. And there is nothing wrong with a comment you had fancy to comment. Just a friendly nudge. The rest is your imagination.

Comment: You **REALLY** need to learn about [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you see valid=%273%27 , it means that you are sending '3' with the single quote.

You could check for the value "'3'"

```
if($_GET['valid']=="'3'")
```

or remove it from the input

```
$valid = intval(str_replace("'",'',$_GET['valid']));
if ($valid == 3)
```

Comment: Or fix the code that generates this url in the first place

Comment: progysm , Thank you so much it worked.It had spoiled my whole day.Thanks a lot there to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to receive a number/integer then [typecast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) your $_GET variable to be an integer value to make sure what you get.

```
$number = (int)$_GET['valid'];
if($valid == 3) { ...
```

You will then notice that your variable is actually not the number `3` but it is a string, `'3'`.

You can also try dumping your variable to see what it really is with:

```
echo var_dump($_GET['valid']);
```

Otherwise as @progysm suggests you can compare on a string level:

```
if($_GET['valid'] == "'3'") { ...
```

Comment: echo (int)"'3'";  gives 0 because of the quote.

Comment: @progysm - yes, correct but it seems the requester expects the input to be an integer so he better make sure he compares with an integer also.

Answer (score 0):

try `$_GET['valid']=="'3'"` in your if statement.